# What is the correct notation for taking the derivative of a partially applied functions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

If we have a function $f(x,y)$ then defining the partial derivatives and total derivative are easily do-able, however if I limit one argument to a constant value, how do I determine the rate of change of this quantity?

Take, for example, the partially applied function $f(x,1)$.

Would the correct notation be $\frac{df(x,1)}{dx}$? One one hand $f(x,1)=g(x)$ and $\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$ is defined so perhaps we can have $\frac{df(x,1)}{dx}=\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$ in the same vein that $y=h(x)$ often means we can use the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dh(x)}{dx}$.

However $f$ being a multivariable function, even if the number represented by $f(x,1)$ changes depending on the value of a single variable $x$ is it more correct then to use the partial derivative notation $\frac{∂f(x,1)}{∂x}$

Could someone suggest the correct notation for this?

And in this case is $\frac{df(x,1)}{dx}$ entirely wrong? Is it better to say that if $y=f(x,1)=g(x)$

$\frac{∂f(x,1)}{∂x}=\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}$

**It seems that through the correct use of the derivative is defined over functions, we can see that using the idea that $y=f(x)$ and the $dy/dx$ notation causes us ambiguity is this an incorrect assumption/incorrect/outdated notation?**

Comment: $\frac{\partial f(x,1)}{\partial x}$ is in my opinion totally correct. An alternative would be $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\Big|_{y=1}$.

Comment: See [Partial derivative: Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Notation)

Comment: The partial derivative of a mononomial function is just an ordinary derivative; so being monovariate is not an issue.

Comment: @KurtG. would it be wrong to say $\frac{d(x,1)}{dx}$ or would this be conflated with the total derivative of $f$?

Comment: To me a notation is mostly neither right nor wrong. It is at best clear and unclear at worst. The variant $\frac{df(x,1)}{dx}$ I have never seen before, most likely for a very good reason which is in line what you wrote in the question.

Comment: @KurtG. if we consider that derivatives are really defined for functions, it makes sense, which begs the question, is our use of $dy/dx$ for $y$ which feels like taking the derivative of a value, incorrect?

Comment: As I said : clear or unclear are better categories when it comes to notation. When you now start a crusade against $dy/dx$ because it looks / feels incorrect you'd have generations of mathematicians from a couple of centuries against you. ***Best*** to underpin every notation that you use with a few clarifying words.

Comment: @KurtG. can we can consider it a slightly outdated notation, because in contexts like this, it doesn't really make sense?

Comment: I am really getting tired of this discussion. $dy/dx$ as such has zero meaning. The *context* defines what $y$ exactly is and this determines if that notation is accurate or not. If $y$ depends on $x$ or is a constant value this notation far from being outdated. Please understand that I am not the international mathematics notation committee.

Answer (score 1):

I've said this on *many* other posts (check out some of my other answers) but we need to remember that differentiation is an operation on *functions*, not variables.

**First point:** You say "if we have a function $f(x,y)$...." - you need to remember that $f(x,y)$ **is not a function**. $f$ is a function, and $f(x,y)$ is the value outputted by $f$ when it is evaluated at the point $(x,y)$.

**Second point:** The vast majority of less experienced mathematicians, and even a fair few more seasoned ones, conflate *variables* and *arguments*. If we have a function of a single variable, say $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and we write $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$, what we *really* mean is "the derivative of $f$ with respect to its *first argument*, which happens to be its first argument. The letter $x$ is simply a useful, but nonetheless completely arbitrary, name that we have given to the argument of $f$. This is where the confusion really begins - what if I choose to name the first argument of $f$ something exotic like $\text{apple}$? Derivatives don't care what you name your arguments, so would it really be correct to say
$$\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm d~\text{apple}}~\text{?}$$
This seems very wrong. This is why, in my own work, I do my best to avoid Leibniz notation like $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\big(f(x)\big)$ as much as possible, except when it's very clear.

---

Ok, that was quite long winded and pedantic. To summarize - Differentiation is an operation on functions, not variables. And variables are kind of dumb; arguments are better.

So, let's suppose we have a two-variable function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$. From this two variable function, we can construct a single variable function. This function takes in the number $x$ and outputs the number $f(x,1)$. A way to write this function is
$$x\mapsto f(x,1)$$
We don't need to give this function a special name. The above notation is enough. It describes, literally, what this function is - takes in $x$, returns $f(x,1)$. Crucially, note that the variable name that we use is unimportant, i.e
$$(x\mapsto f(x,1))=(b\mapsto f(b,1))$$
This is a statement of equivalence of *functions*. The two sides of the equation don't have the same numerical value, because they are not numbers. Instead, they are equivalent objects - they are both functions which do the same thing when given the same input.

Hence, we can, in a totally unambiguous way, write the derivative of this function as
$$\mathrm D(t\mapsto f(t,1))$$
Again this is a *function*, not a number. The value that this function takes at a number, say $x$, is
$$\mathrm D(t\mapsto f(t,1))(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,1)-f(x,1)}{h}$$

Comment: I think what confuses me is things like $dy/dx$ where we take the derivative of what seemingly looks like a variable, so $df(x,y)/dx$ to me felt like the derivative of the value given by $f(x,1)$ wrt to $x$ and not the derivative of $f$ at $(x,1)$. So the partial derivative of $f$ is equivalent to the standard derivative of $g$, is this correct?

Comment: @user37577 Partial derivatives aren't really anything different to "ordinary derivatives", so yes.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, this makes sense, if I am going to write anything with $f$ I should use the partial derivative because its the partial derivative on $f$. Great answer